# Constraining CSS class styles to apply only to a given id

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I am trying to use two Twitter Bootstrap navs on the same page. I have written some css to style them. Problem is, I want the css to apply to just one of the navs. I tried to use css ids to distinguish the two navs, but am having trouble getting the selectors right. Can anyone help?

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/XVReX/

HTML:

```
<div id="something" class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li id="selectEventStep"><a>Select Event</a>

                </li>
                <li id="selectPriceStep"><a>Select Price</a>

                </li>
                <li id="confirmSwapStep"><a>Confirm Swap</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li id="selectEventStep"><a>Select Event</a>

                </li>
                <li id="selectPriceStep"><a>Select Price</a>

                </li>
                <li id="confirmSwapStep"><a>Confirm Swap</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#something.navbar #something.navbar-inner {
    padding: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E5665D, #C4564F);
}
#something.navbar #something.nav li a {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFE2E0;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
    ;
}
#something.navbar #something.nav li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selectors are more complicated than necessary and the syntax is incorrect - you can override bootstrap.css by instead using:

`#something .navbar-inner { }`

`#something .nav li a{  }`

`#something .nav li a:hover {  }`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XVReX/4/)

Comment: Sorry just realized I was using webkit gradients which wont work in non webkit browsers

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the entire style sheet to apply the style only on those elements with a class name .bootstrap using sass compiler and regular expression which looks like this

```
 audio.bootstrap:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
}
 html.bootstrap {
  font-size: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
 a.bootstrap:focus {
  outline: thin dotted #333;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

I haven't checked everything but I think it works alright.

**http://jsfiddle.net/Lc5h6/**